# PHP: Form not submitting

Tags: php

So i go to click submit on my form, however when i submit nothing happens and my form does not submit my data nor store into the database. Please see the code below, i do know the code is all in one and i will split it all up after.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO reviews (name, content)
          VALUES('" . $_POST['name'] . "',
                 '" . $_POST['content'] . "')";


  $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";

  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
  $conn->close();
  }

  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM reviews";

  $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if ($results === false) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
  }else {
    $reviews = mysqli_fetch_all($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  }

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Leave a review</h2>
<form>

Name: <input type="text" name="name">

<br>
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"> </textarea>
<br>
<button>Add Review</button>

<h2>Review</h2>
<?php


?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Debugging is a priceless skill in the world of programming. Take some time to [learn how to do some basic debugging](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/). After you've become comfortable with the basics, you can have a look at a [more extensive tutorial](https://stackify.com/php-debugging-guide/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements default to `method="GET"`.

To make a POST request and to include the form data in the request body where it will populate `$_POST` in PHP you need to explicitly set the `method` attribute to `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

At the top your PHP script fetches a value from `$_POST['content']` (to put it into the table's "content" row), but you textareas `name` is "comment" (should be identical)!